# Error converting data type varchar to numeric SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a column of type `DECIMAL(8,0)`.

I'm trying to update a blank/space/empty sting(' ') based on condition.

```
update table1 
set col1 = cast('' as decimal(8,0))
where value = '5'
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

How to update blank/space/empty sting(' ') in the column of decimal datatype?

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert whitespace to a decimal data type.

Comment: I think, there must be some ways to do it? Can we put NULL ?

Comment: You can if it's a nullable column.  update table1 set col1 = 
     null
  where 
  value = 5